# Adding values to an array with a function javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, canvas

Background info to the problem:
What I am trying to do is every time a user clicks a button I want to convert a canvas to the dataURL value and then store that value in an array. So far I can get the data URL reference but it only ever adds one value to the array.

The function "dataurl" gets the canvas an creates the dataURL:
Code:

```
function dataurl () {

var a = document.getElementById("theCanvas");
var context = a.getContext("2d");
var img = document.createElement("img");
var dataURL = a.toDataURL();





addToArray(dataURL);

}
```

It then calls the addToArray function (I have created the array outside the function):

```
myImages = new Array();
function addToArray(URL){
//  alert(URL);
    myImages.push(URL);
    alert(myImages.length);


}
```

The alert always comes out as 1.
the dataurl function is initially called when the user clicks a button:

```
 <input class="button" type="submit" name="save" value="Save" onclick="dataurl();"/>
```

The reason I'm trying to add these to an array is to store images (at the bottom) on screen of the canvas when the user hits the save button.

Comment: Have you checked that you aren't re-defining `myImages = new Array();` each time (could be reason why it's always 1)? I'd suggest creating a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to demonstrate your problem?

Comment: I was thinking about that, too. There's the only thing I can think of

Comment: I get you, but I don't see how it could be re-defining if it is outside the function

Answer (score 0):

You're alerting the length of the array, myImages.length.
Change to alert(myImages);

```
function addToArray(URL){
 //  alert(URL);
    myImages.push(URL);
    alert(myImages);
}
```

Comment: I was alerting the length as a check to see if the dataURLs were being added correctly.